# Morphology Fill Halo in Binary Matrix

Tags: opencv, image-processing

[image: img]

Is there any way using OpenCV to set the center hole of the halo to white pixels so I can get a solid white circle? I have tried using dilate and erode morphological functions. They make the image more clear (as you are seeing), but the center remains black.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply find the external contour, and then fill the whole contour:

[image]

Code:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // Read grayscale image
    Mat1b img = imread("path_to_image", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    // Find external contour
    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    findContours(img.clone(), contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    // Check that you find something
    if (!contours.empty())
    {
        // Fill the first (and only) contour with white
        drawContours(img, contours, 0, Scalar(255), CV_FILLED);
    }

    // Show result
    imshow("Filled", img);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```